# merge asp.net mvc with existing asp.net app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, merge

I have merged and asp.net 4.0 app with a asp.net mvc 3 app.

Everything works, except for the gravy like right clicking on the Controllers folder and getting:

Add >> Add Controller

Same for Views, etc, etc.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the corresponding `.csproj` file using your favorite text editor (Not Visual Studio) and add the following:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    ...

    <ProjectTypeGuids>{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325};Some other guids which are not important</ProjectTypeGuids>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Notice the `{F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}` guid. This is what indicates that it's an ASP.NET MVC 2 project and you should get Visual Studio menus.

If this is an ASP.NET MVC 3 RC project the guid is `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}`.

Comment: Many thanks, I had just figured that out, but happy to give you the biscuit.  Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple add another project in your solution by opening porject file of mvc app in sub folder.

That will resolve you problem.

I hope this will help